# Data in Variable Explorer is not available for debugging in Spyder 4

Tags: python, spyder

Let's say I have 2 Python files: `file1.py` and `file2.py`. The latter needs a set of data generated by `file1.py`. However, when I start debugging `file2.py` (or any other Python file), all the data in the Variable Explorer disappear and only reappear when I stop the debugging mode. This doesn't happen in Spyder 3. Is it a bug in Spyder 4 or I miss something? How to solve this problem?

Note: I don't check the *Remove all variables before execution* in the Preferences.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) So you execute `file1.py` first and then proceed to debug `file2.py`?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Yes, that's how I do it, and it's necessary that I do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To make the data generated by `file1.py` available to `file2.py`, you need to give focus to `file2.py` in the editor, then go to the menu

`Run > Configuration per file`

and finally activate the option called

`Run in console's namespace instead of an empty one`